# Auto instrument Next.js 13 API endpoint request & response

Tags: logging, next.js, open-telemetry

I'm running a small Next.js project. It has some API endpoints that get called by other applications. I'd like to instrument these endpoints so that the incoming request and the response are automatically logged. What's the preferred way to do this in (almost) 2024?

I already have logs being sent to a log dump, and I can see the API requests via stdout, but it's not including the request/response data.

I see there is an [experimental instrumentation feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation), but looking at the [default OpenTelemetry spans](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/open-telemetry#default-spans-in-nextjs), I don't think this will achieve what I'm looking for.

`next@13.5.4`

Comment: As per this discussion, middleware won't work: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30681